# Django - Return Pdf and JsonResponse using same class instance

Tags: python, django

I have a view that return a JsonResponse. I want to generate a pdf report using the Building instance (the structure variable).

For example, the view that return the JsonResponse is:

```
   @login_required
    def buildings(request):
        if request.POST and request.is_ajax():
            s_form = BuildingForm(request.POST)
            if s_form.is_valid():
                structure = Building(**s_form.cleaned_data)
                html = render_to_string('wind/results/buildings/buildings_results.html', {'structure': structure})
                return JsonResponse({"result": html})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'building_errors': s_form.errors,
                                    status=400)
        else:
            s_form = BuildingForm()
            return render(request, 'wind/buildings.html', {'s_form': s_form})
```

I have the following code for generate and return the pdf:

```
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Report.pdf"'
    buffer = BytesIO()
    report = BuildingsReport(structure)  # I want to use the same Building instance
    pdf = report.generate_pdf()
    response.write(pdf)
    return response
```

What I want is use the same building instance for generating the pdf and the html variable.

Using a different view to return the pdf implies a new Building instance. Except that there is another solution that solves the problem using another view.

In the Frontend I want to show the JsonResponse and have the pdf available for the user to download using a html button.

Using Celery is adecuated for this task?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine if you want to use the same view to send two different formats, in fact, many API's will give you the option of stating which format you want to receive, like this:

```
/buildings?format=pdf
```

You can parse this with a view like this:

```
def buildings(request):
    format = request.GET.get('format', 'html').lower() # HTML is the default method
    if format is 'pdf':
        return create_PDF_response(request) # create your PDF
    elif format is 'json':
        return carry_on_with_JSON_response(request)
    return the_default_HTML_response(request)
```

**Now, about using Celery:** When you know tasks are going to hog the machine for a long time, like creating a heavy PDF, it's best to take those tasks out of the response flow. This creates a lot of other problems you'll need to figure out, but it's going to look something like this:

1. Receive request to create a PDF
2. Create a celery task and save some kind of state on a model or somewhere.
3. Send back a response saying that the PDF is being created.
4. Start polling the state of the task...
5. When the celery task is done, change the state of the model or whatever.
6. Stop polling and notify the user that the file is ready to download.
7. Take the user to the download somehow, preferably using a button, as any kind of download that's not a product of user interaction is seen as an attack by many browsers.

If your machine is not up to it, or your user load is too much that you can't generate the PDF's before your requests time out, then you should use Celery, but many PDF's can be generated quickly and simple.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a question about the first part of the answer. The code have the choices to generate a pdf or a html. If I call the view function for html and then for pdf the class is called twice and generate the results twice?

This is how the results are showed in the browser.


[Results](https://i.imgur.com/WV6fU07.png)

Comment: About the second part of the answer I'll investigate the use of Celery. I now I can delay a task in the view, but how can I call later using the button showed in the image?, from an url refer to other view?

Comment: -first: if you send two requests to a view, the view will generate two responses, HTTP is a stateless protocol, it's your responsibility to cache any intermediate results you want to share between the two responses.

-second: you may need to write another view for checking the state (that would output the state of the task), and another view to request the file, that would handle Content-Disposition header to download the file, those are totally different questions altogether.

Comment: I understand, I think I'll try with Celery. Thanks again.